# Why recast a variable to a type if it already is that type?

Tags: java, casting

I was examining some professionally written code and came across this fragment. (I hope this fragment is sufficient to answer my question - if not let me know)

```
...yada yada yada ....

private ITypedElement format(final ITypedElement elementToFormat) {
        try {
            if (elementToFormat instanceof IStreamContentAccessor) {
                final IStreamContentAccessor resNode = (IStreamContentAccessor) elementToFormat;
                final InputStream contentIs = resNode.getContents();
                final String contentsString = fromInputStreamToString(contentIs);
                final Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
.... etc....
```

The `if` segment only runs if `elementToFormat` is an instance of `IStreamContentAccessor`. Why then did the program make the first statement after the `if` statement, "`final IStreamContentAccessor resNode = (IStreamContentAccessor)elementToFormat;"`?

What could possibly be the point of casting something to a type it must already be?

Comment: `"Why recast a variable to a type if it already is that type?"` -- but the variable ***isn't*** "that" type. The object is, but the variable that references it isn't, and that's a key distinction. If you need to use methods of that specific type, then you need to cast the variable to the object's type.

Answer (score 5):

The programmer may know that it's a `IStreamContentAccessor`, but without the cast the compiler doesn't know that it's a `IStreamContentAccessor` and so it won't let the programmer access any of the fields/methods specific to the `IStreamContentAccessor` class.

```
class ClassA {
    Object field1;
}

class ClassB extends ClassA
    Object field2;
}

ClassA obj = new ClassB();
obj.field1;  // This is fine, the compiler knows it's a ClassA
obj.field2;  // This isn't allowed - as far as the compiler knows it's a ClassA, not a ClassB
((ClassB)obj).field2;  // This is allowed - now the compiler knows it's a ClassB
```

Comment: It's important to note that, in Java, the `(ClassName)` cast generates a `checkcast` bytecode that actually checks to be sure that the object is of the specified class (or is a subclass of the specified class).  If the object is not the correct class then a ClassCastException is thrown.

Comment: And it's not just the compiler that requires this.  The bytecode verifier in the JVM checks that types are consistent, and will refuse to load the class if they aren't.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it the compiler compiling or the JVM running the bytecode that needs the cast? IE would `obj.field2` fail to compile or throw an exception when run?

Comment: It would fail to compile, or as Hot Licks pointed out the bytecode would fail to load if e.g. you tweaked the compiled bytecode by hand to remove the checkcast.  On the other hand, if you perform an illegal cast, e.g. casting a `ClassA` to a `ClassC` that isn't a parent or child of `ClassA`, then the program would compile/load correctly but you'd then get a runtime `ClassCastException`

Comment: ...but in your example, `obj instanceof ClassB` would return true, even though the statement `obj.field2` (which implies `obj` **IS NOT** an instance of ClassB) is not allowed??

Comment: That's correct - there are complex type inference algorithms that the compiler could use to (possibly) determine the true type of `obj`, but Java simply uses the declared type of `obj` to determine what methods/fields are available and leaves it up to the programer to cast the object as appropriate.  It's a tradeoff between ease of programming and compilation speed/simplicity, with Java favoring the latter in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statement guarantees that the object is an instance of that type. However, to the JVM, the object is still of type `ITypedElement`. Just because *you* now know that it's valid doesn't mean that the JVM knows.

The cast allows you to access the methods of `IStreamContentAccessor`. You will notice that without the cast, if you just refer to `elementToFormat` with methods that `ITypedElement` does not have but `IStreamContentAccessor` does, you will get an error.

For example:

```
Animal a;
a = new Dog();
// "a" contains a Dog in memory, but we only KNOW that it's an Animal
// because that is its declared type

a.bark(); // fails at compile time - not all Animals can bark

Dog d = (Dog) a;
// This is a valid cast, because Dog extends Animal, but it's potentially unsafe.
//
// Another "valid" cast is:
// Cat c = (Cat) a
// but this would fail at runtime (ClassCastException) because the actual
// object in memory (a Dog) cannot be cast to a Cat.

if (a instanceof Dog) {
    // Now we KNOW that it's a Dog and we can cast safely.
    Dog d2 = (Dog) a;
    d2.bark(); // this is valid because d2's declared type is Dog
}
```

So, to summarize,

- the cast grants you access to the fields of the subclass
- the `if` statement ensures that the cast is valid
- the two statements are technically completely independent
- you are smarter than the JRE

Comment: If I would type `System.out.println(a instanceof Dog)` after the first two lines of comment, I would get `False`?

Comment: No, you would get `true`, because `a` is an instance of `Dog` in *memory*; that's what `instanceof` is for. (By the way, Java uses `true`/`false`, not `True`/`False`.)

Comment: Huh? If `a` is in fact an instance of `Dog`, why do you say I can't `bark()` with it?

Comment: Because, as [Hovercraft Full of Eels points out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449566/why-recast-a-variable-to-a-type-if-it-already-is-that-type/16449602?noredirect=1#comment23595796_16449566), you don't *know* it's a `Dog`. Java wants to be sure that you can do something before you do it.

Comment: ??? If the `if` statement is executing, and the condition was the `a` must be a `Dog`, then YOU DO know it's a `Dog`! I'm so confused

Comment: @Imray: You're still confusing variables with the objects that they refer to. If a is declared as an Animal *variable*, then it only has access to Animal methods, even if it references a Dog object. Again, if you want to be able to use Dog methods that are not available in Animal, you need to do the instanceof and the cast. 1+ to the WChargin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is annoying, but is required by the Java language.

The variable elementToFormat is of type ITypedElement. To use it as an IStreamContentAccessor requires casting.

In this specific case, we can see that the local parameter must be of the cast type. However, the right-hand side of the assignment could be something other than a local parameter -- for example, a member variable, or a function call. The same type-checking rules apply consistently to the right-hand value, regardless where it's coming from.

This idiom is annoying because we have to *repeat the type three times*. This means a little extra work for us. But -- since downcasting is sometimes a code smell -- we could consider this idiom to be a little syntactic salt.

Answer (score 0):

This `final IStreamContentAccessor resNode = (IStreamContentAccessor) elementToFormat;` is stated because `elementToFormat` is not of type `IStreamContentAccessor` but it can safely be cast into it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the interfaces and class below:

```
interface ITypedElement
{
    //...
}

interface IStreamContentAccessor
{
    InputStream getContents();
}

class Demo implements ITypedElement, IStreamContentAccessor
{
    //
}
```

Demo class implements both the classes and can be sent as:

```
ITypedElement demoInstance = new Demo();

format(demoInstance);
```

now `demoInstance` can also be used an *instance* of `IStreamContentAccessor`.

Edit 1:

Okay, so let us say that Demo class can *behave* both like `ITypedElement` and `IStreamContentAccessor`. If we create an instance of Demo class, it can display behaviours of both the interfaces and a variable can be created that points to that instance such that it extracts only the behaviour we are interested in.

```
Demo d = new Demo();
//d is an instance that can perform everything that `Demo` class is supposed to perform which includes behaviour of the two interfaces as well.

ITypedElement iti = (ITypedElement)d;
// Is above valid? Yes, because Demo implements ITypedElement.
// and we just extracted the `ITypedElement` *behaviour* from `d`.

//similarly 
IStreamContentAccessor isa = (IStreamContentAccessor)d;
// Is above valid? Yes, because Demo implements IStreamContentAccessor.
// and we just extracted the `IStreamContentAccessor` *behaviour* from `d`.

//Can we do something like
IStreamContentAccessor isaTough = (IStreamContentAccessor)iti;
// Yes, of course, and this brings up something rather interesting
// Even if we create a variable (`iti`) that *points* to an instance `d`
// it doesn't lose its original nature, rather we only see the behaviour
// we are interested in i.e `ITypedElement`.
```

Essentially `iti`, `isa`, `d` and `isaTough` are all the same thing limited by the behaviour forced upon them by the design of their contracts viz: `ITypedElement`, `IStreamContentAccessor`, `Demo` and `IStreamContentAccessor` respectively.

I think I just made it a little more complicated than it should have been, prolly someone else might explain better?

Comment: Aha ok. But what's confusing is we're saying in the format method that if `demoInstance` is an instance of `IStreamContentAccessor` then cast `demoInstance` to `IStreamContentAccessor`. I can understand if the action we take is something like cast `demoInstance` to `ITypedElement`, but why cast to something EXACTLY the same as the type it already is?? Your answer doesn't explain that clearly